# jquery change() alert fires 6 times for one click?

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('.c5sliderSelect').change(function() 
    {
        alert('change clicked');
    });
});
```

When I change the select list item, I get 6 alerts. Not sure why. I only have one element in the markup with this classname and the select list has 10 option items.

Any ideas why the alert fires more than once for a single change event?

Markup:

```
<select 
    class="c5sliderSelect" 
    title="Note: only categories which have posts assigned are listed here"> 
    <option value="">Custom Text</option> 
    <option value="164">Blog (10)</option>
    <option value="8">Digital Cameras (3)</option>
    <option value="9">GPS Systems (1)</option>
    <option value="7">Healthy Herbal Teas (1)</option>
    <option value="93">hidden (1)</option>
    <option value="20">iPhone 4s (2)</option>
    <option value="5">Samsung Galaxy (5)</option>
    <option value="4">Smart Phones (5)</option>
    <option value="1">Uncategorized (7)</option>
</select>
```

***What I'm trying to do here is to hide an unrelated div when the selected item's value is ""***

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Maybe you are binding the event handler more than once? Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: which jquery version are you using?

Comment: can you host this on jsfiddle so that we can see the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using something other than `alert`. `alert` has horrible effects on focus, and of course the `change` event relates to `focus`. Try `console.log` or similar.

For instance, [this live example](http://jsbin.com/ugazul) using your markup shows only a single `change` event being fired.

Comment: Looking at console.log now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

Use `click()` binding to catch clicks and use `$` or `jQuery.noConflict()` to guarantee no conflicts with other javascript libraries.

#### Samples

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.c5sliderSelect').click(function() 
    {
        alert('change clicked');
    });
});
```

or

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('.c5sliderSelect').click(function() 
    {
        alert('change clicked');
    });
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)
- [jQuery.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

### Update

Just to clarify, using `click()` is a mouse event, it does not captures changes using the keyboard.

Comment: What's wrong with using `jQuery`? If you suggest using `click` you should also mention that it won't capture changes done with the keyboard.

Comment: Dont believe this should matter unless he is using two versions of jquery or some other library that overrides jquery. and also the click event will not capture all the events that he probably wants

Answer (score 1):

This means that for your jQuery script the element exists 6 times. You might have initialized the element 6 times or in your case the element $('.c5sliderSelect') is changed by some script, but the above script is not enough to determine this.

Comment: I did a barebones version of your script and it works fine! Alert fires one time. There must be something else that makes it fire multiple times!

Comment: this helped me. In my case I had an MVC editor model getting created multiple times with this piece of script in it. So I had remove the script and take it up a few levels so it was only injected once.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a click function use:

```
$('.c5sliderSelect').click(function()
```

change may not be the correct event you are looking for...